# Python - module Crypt

Tags: python, module, cryptography

I began to work with python and I have a problem with module Crypto.
I tried use it in pycharm and I got error message -  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

So, I checked in the cmd and it not install in my pc.
I tried in a lot of way to install this but its not succeed.
It was I wrote in cmd:   `pip install pycrypto`
its seem he download it but finally I got a error :

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\danie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pw_edinw\\pycrypto_5bc451b70616472ca18501e6ab47feb3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\danie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pw_edinw\\pycrypto_5bc451b70616472ca18501e6ab47feb3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3hlrh787\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Someone can help me - It is important for the next work and I can't solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: IIRC it may rely on a linux system library, so not available under windows ‍♂️. Maybe try with Cygwin??

Comment: maybe you should be using pip3, `pip3 install pycryptdome`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use PyCryptodome instead of PyCrypto.

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html

Here's what PyCryptodome said:

> PyCryptodome exposes almost the same API as the old PyCrypto so that most applications will run unmodified.

And it is much more easier to install on new Python version:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

And boom, it's done!

Comment: thanks.I Think I have a problem with the 'from'. I succeed to install but I cant find the model in the pycharm. Do you have a idea why?   Maybe I have a problem with the root of the 'from'?

Comment: @Daniel_shlomo It should be pycharm's configuration problem. Check the Python interpreter at the bottom right, make sure it is the SAME environment with your pip which installed pycryptodome.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @Daniel_shlomo If you think it's useful, please accept my answer! Thank you!